# How to get a rectangle around a polygon?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

I have a polygon with all coordinates known. I want to draw a rectangle around it making $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ as it's base. How can I get new coordinates forming rectangle around polygon?
[image: polygon]

```
(x1,y1) = (8.375, 127.5258)
(x2,y2) = (26.1326, 127.5258)   
(x3,y3) = (26.375,  130.5258)   
(x4,y4) = (23.6995, 141.2277)   
(x5,y5) = (8.375,   137.3966)
```

Comment: Now, what do you think about the problem?

Comment: How to create a rectangle with the values I have and forming with new coordinates for it.

Comment: Do you want all vertices of the polygon to touch the rectangle?

Comment: yes, all the vertices need to touch rectangle.

Comment: @AlexDave, it is impossible in general. Consider a polygon with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (0.75,0.75)$.

Comment: @Zeekless Did you read question?

Comment: How are you constraining this problem?  For example, is the polygon always convex?  Is it uncrossed? Does the base of the rectangle have to be co-linear with one side of the rectangle?  etc?

Comment: @DrPeterMcGowan polygon is always convex. If the polgon is concave, then it will touch only the coordinates outside and maximum leaving the concave coordinate. Base will always be collinear with the rectangle.

Comment: Is it correct that $y_1=y_2$? I am looking at given numbers.

Comment: @Zeekless in this case, y1 = y2 but not in all the cases.

Comment: @AlexDave, you can calculate coordinates of the vertices using my answer. Preview: upper-left vertex is (8.3750,  141.2277).

Comment: @Zeekless thank you very much Zeekless. I am checking with your formula.

Comment: @AlexDave, you may ask if something is not clear.

Comment: An algorithm for a convex polygon. Drop perpendiculars $u_i$ on line joining $(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2)$  and find max/min.  Similarly drop perpendiculars $v_i$ on an arbitrary  line perpendicular to the earlier line joining $(x_1,y_1)-(x_2,y_2) $  and find max/min. Pickup four paired points from intersection of these four selected lines.

Answer (score 2):

[Rotate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Derivation) the figure by angle $-\arctan\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ so that the side $12$ becomes horizontal, and determine the axis-aligned bounding box (which is trivial).

Then rotate the four corners back in place (if needed).

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me the new coordinates of rectangle for the values which I have given! I implemented in the formula but I am not sure of the exact coordinates. Please elaborate your answer with values.

Comment: @AlexDave: sorry, no, this is not a free problem resolution service. Check graphically.

Comment: @AlexDave, my answer gives you the exact formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by fixing the direction of a side of the rectangle in any way (it need not be one of the sides of the polygon).

So let $(x_1, y_1), ..., (x_n, y_n)$ be the vertices of the polygon, and let $(a,b)$ be a vector which is parallel to a side of the desired rectangle.

You need to find the line equation of the sides of the rectangle. 
As $(a,b)$ is a normal to two of them and parallel to the other two, two of the line equations have the form:

$$ax+by+c=0$$

and the other two have the form:

$$bx-ay+c=0$$.

I show you how to find the first two, the other two is analogous ($c$ is the unknown). Let $\ell$ be the line that consists of the endpoints of the multiples of the vector $(a,b)$. So $\ell$ consists of the points $(at, bt)$, $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

So we are looking for two line equations of the form $ax+by+c=0$, with $c$ being unknown. By altering $c$, we are shifting a line perpendicular to the vector $(a,b)$. The projection of the polygon to the line $\ell$ is a segment, and the extreme positions where the shifted line touches the polygon are those vertices of the polygon whose projection to $\ell$ are the endpoints of this segment. 
So you are looking for the vertices $(x_i, y_i)$ such that the projection of $(x_i, y_i)$ to $\ell$ are "leftmost" and "rightmost" on $\ell$, that is, $ax_i+by_i$ are minimal or maximal. (The projections to $\ell$ are the points corresponding to the scalar product if you view $\ell$ as the real line.) So find i such that $ax_i+by_i$ is minimal, and let this minimum be $c_1$. Also find i such that $ax_i+by_i$ is maximal, and let this maximum be $c_2$. Then the two line equations we were looking for are $ax+by-c_1=0$ and $ax+by-c_2=0$.

Answer (score -1):

I will denote $v_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix} x_j \\ y_j \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} x_i \\ y_i \end{bmatrix}$, that is the vector from $i$-point to $j$-point.

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} +\frac{v_{12} \cdot v_{23}}{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert} \Big(\frac{v_{12}}{{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert}}\Big) = \text{ coordinates of lower-right vertex}.
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{bmatrix} +\frac{v_{12} \cdot v_{15}}{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert} \Big(\frac{v_{12}}{{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert}}\Big)= \text{ coordinates of lower-left vertex}.
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_4 \\ y_4 \end{bmatrix} +\frac{v_{12} \cdot v_{43}}{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert}\Big(\frac{v_{12}}{{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert}}\Big) = \text{ coordinates of upper-right vertex}.
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_4 \\ y_4 \end{bmatrix} +\frac{v_{12} \cdot v_{45}}{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert} \Big(\frac{v_{12}}{{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert}}\Big)= \text{ coordinates of upper-left vertex}.
$$

Fractions like $\frac{v_{12} \cdot v_{45}}{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert}$ are the projections of sides of the polygon onto the direction of the base, while $\Big(\frac{v_{12}}{{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert}}\Big)$ is a unit vector of the base direction.

Comment: Now what if the polygon has six vertices ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, general answer is that the problem may be unsolvable (see my comment to the original question). That is why I am giving a solution to this particular case.

Comment: Unsolvable ? No, it is always solvable, unless there are vertices on either sides of $12$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, see comments to the original question. AlexDave wants all vertices to touch the rectangle. It is not always possible.

Comment: Mh, I am not convinced that the OP understood this in the general case. But we can't know. Anyway, it is easy to solve the problem without that constraint, or to check that the constraint is achievable.

Comment: Anyway, my answer seems to be correct now :) That's good enough for me.

Comment: It is pretty ad-hoc, when a general solution is not much more complicated.

Comment: @AlexDave, $v_{45}$ must have negative coordinates. And you have wrong $\Vert v_{12} \Vert$.

Comment: In this polygon, V34, V45 and V51 will have negative direction and others are positive. But ||V12|| = sqrt(x2-x1). Am I right? Then I am getting ||V12|| = 17.7576.

Comment: @AlexDave,  $v_{45}$ has two negative coordinates. $v_{51}$ has one  zero and one negative. $v_{15}$ has one zero and one positive. $\Vert v_{12} \Vert = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$

Comment: How can V45 have negative coordinates? v12⋅v45 means distance between coordinates 12 and 45 and fianlly dot product! https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/distance-two-points.php?a=23.6995%2C141.2277&b=8.375%2C137.3966&action=solve

Comment: @AlexDave, firstly, $v_{45} = \begin{bmatrix} x_5 \\ y_5 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} x_4 \\ y_4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} <0 \\ <0 \end{bmatrix}$. Secondly, $v_{12} \cdot v_{45}$ is a dot product, but not a distance. Sorry, man, I am getting sick of it.

Comment: @Zeekless sorry Zeekless, now I am getting all x values correct but y values wrong. not sure what I am doing wrong. for example, I am taking only  x2 in lower right formula but i got rectangle LR x2 value as 26.375 and y2 as 127.7682. just replaced y2 in the place of x2.

Comment: @AlexDave $\frac{v_{12} \cdot v_{23}}{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert} \Big(\frac{\color{red}{v_{12}}}{{\Vert{v_{12}}\Vert}}\Big) $ When calculating the second coordinate, you have to take the second coordinate of the red term as well. It is 0, by the way.